# Is there a StockTwits User Profile API endpoint?

Tags: api, stocktwits

Specifically, a call I can make to get all metadata about a user's profile?

`curl -XGET http://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/user.json?username=bgajdero`

This would return a JSON string with their id, name, avatar, bio, etc.

I'm looking at the [API Docs](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api), but don't see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you click on "Show Extended" in the [user stream end-point](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#streams-user-docs), you'll see more metadata in that user's profile as you mentioned, which isn't available publicly.

To get access to that extended metadata, you will need partner-level access to our API, which you can apply for here: http://stocktwits.com/developers/contact

Comment: Thanks Sayem. I'll apply for the access.

Comment: This one is better than the user stream end-point if I just need to get the avatar right ? => http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#search-users-docs

Comment: Well, even better, I used this method instead (http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#account-verify-docs) to retrieve the id, name, username & avatar. You just need to pass the token and you're done.